# Mysql creates new thread connection on each refresh page

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, connection, database-connection

When I refresh the php page,mysql creating new thread connection,and this cause problem on shared host due to limit of max_user_connection.Limit is 30 and I refresh the page 30 times,mysql stops and displays `User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections`.
I think I set up correctly but can't find solution.

**db.php**

```
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$db="terind";
mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

**head.php**

```
require("db.php");

...codes...
```

**end.php**

```
mysql_close();
```

**index.php**

```
require("head.php");
$check=mysql_fetch_assoc(...);
echo $check['index'];
require("end.php");
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated and don't support prepared statements (which you should be using). Also, when the script terminates the connection should be dropped as well, unless your shared hosting is keeping scripts alive for some reason. Try adding a `die()` at the end of `end.php` and see if that helps.

Comment: die(mysql_error()) didn't display any error

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by not accessing the database directly, but instead using some kind of connection pool. This is probably not very easy to do on a shared hosting environment.

You could check whether it's possible to run in e.g. PHP-FPM mode with a limited number of worker processes. You could ask the hosting provider to limit the number of webserver workers to the number of connections allowed, of adjust the number of connections to the number of workers.